# Display another container on input:focus using only css

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I want to have some css properties on input:focus so how can I do that?
My scenario is; when input get focus I want to show another div so how can I do that using only css?

On hover I can do that using ">" but on focus is not working and I don;t understand why :(.

so this is my code:

```
<div class="containerTooltipXxx">
 <p class="paragraphClass">
     Some text...<br /><input type="radio" /><br />More text...
     </p><div class="blocks">
<label>Field</label>  <input></input></div>
</div>




  .containerTooltipXxx{
        padding: 20px; 
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid lime;
        margin: 50px;
    }

    .paragraphClass{display: none;}

.containerTooltipXxx:hover > .paragraphClass, .containerTooltipXxx:focus > .paragraphClass{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top:-5px;
        left: 50px;
        background: red;
        opacity:.9;
    }
```

very important, the html hierarchy cannot be changed. 
Thank you.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMfvx/199/)**

Comment: So you dont want hover at all?

Comment: @Sowmya nope, I want to show that .paragraphClass only on input:focus. I want to have the same behavior from hover on focus.

Answer (score 6):

using CSS you can only point to the next sibling elements. Here since the p tag is out of the parent div it is not possible using css.

I know that you don't want to change the HTML order but still I am showing it for example.

Moving p tag inside the `div.blocks` can do this with only CSS

```
.blocks input[type="text"]:focus ~ .paragraphClass {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    opacity:.7;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DMfvx/203/)**

Comment: thank you but I already said, I cannot change html hierarchy so the paragraf must be otside of div class="blocks" :(

Answer (score 3):

```
.containerTooltipXxx:hover >  replace this by
.containerTooltipXxx:focus ~ .paragraphClass
{
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left: 50px;
    background: red;
    opacity:.9;
}
```

Comment: I have the same answer below given by "Sowmya" but I already said, I cannot change html hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Your first hover selector is fine, but the second is wrong.

What you are doing with `.containerTooltipXxx:focus > .paragraphClass`, is selecting the immediate child .paragraphClass from a focused .containerTooltipXxx. Focus can only be used on things with input, and your container is just a div.

What you would need is a parent selector, but these are currently not available. They will be most likely in CSS4. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Currently, your best bet would be using javascript. Make an event listener for focus on the input box, and then programmatically apply a visible class to what you want to show.